# In which Honorverse novel did Honor Harrington first attend the naval academy?

Tags: story-identification, novel, honorverse

In which *[Honorverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse)* novel did Honor Harrington first attend the naval academy and meet Michelle Henke?

I am unable to find that novel.

Comment: I don't know if there is one; the short story ["Ms. Midshipwoman Harrington"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?100868) takes place immediately _after_ her 3 years on Saganami Island, but before she receives her commission.  It refers to Henke, and there are references to events at Saganami Island, but no detailed account.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such novel. Anything that involves her first-time Academy time is mentioned in retrospective only, by either Honor herself or people who were there as well.
Anything you'd like to know about that is like a gleaning: you have to watch out for that while reading books. I don't believe it will be as often in later ones, though.